# Tensor Product Between Matrices Index Notation

Tags: tensor-products

Are there any nice ways of encoding tensor products of matrices using index notation? I.e. for standard matrix multiplication we have

$$(AB)_{ij} = \sum_k A_{ik} B_{kj} $$

Is there anything similar for tensor products?

$$(A\otimes B)_{ij} = ???$$

Answer (score 3):

If by "tensor product" you mean the [Kronecker product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kronecker_product), then we can write in block-matrix notation
$$
(A \otimes B) =  [a_{ij}B]_{i,j = 1}^n
$$
Another thing you can say is that if $B$ is $m \times n$, then
$$
(A \otimes B)_{(i-1)m + p,(j-1)n + q} = a_{ij}b_{pq}
$$